# WPF XAML StringFormat. Escape %

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a field which contains a percantage value as a decimal.

A text block is bound to this field and I want to display it with a % symbol.

For example:
If myfield = 5.0 then text should be displayed as "5.00 %"

This is my binding:

```
Text="{Binding Path=myfield, StringFormat=0.00## \%}"
```

which currently displays "500.00 %"

The '\' does not appear to be escaping the '%'.

How can I escape the '%' in the XAML StringFormat?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there is another zero width character between the backslash and `%` (however unlikely that may appear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like we need to double the slashes, I think the `\` itself need to be escaped to help XAML compiler understand that it is a single `\` before it being combined with `%` to make a perfect escape for `%` which will be understood as literal string `%` by the `StringFormat` (not by XAML compiler):

```
Text="{Binding Path=myfield, StringFormat=0.00## \\%}"
```

So technically we have 2 interpreters here, one by XAML compiler and one by the `StringFormat` engine. Note that the `\` is also used to escape some special characters in XAML, such as the `{` and `}`.

By specifying the parameter index explicitly, you can do this:

```
Text="{Binding Path=myfield, StringFormat=\{0:0.00## \\%\}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with quotes instead:

```
Text="{Binding Path=myfield, StringFormat=0.00## '%'}"
```

Comment: This wont even compile I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to my problem however it does not completly answer my question:

```
 Text="{Binding Path=myfield, StringFormat={}{0:0.00##} %}"
```

This says for parameter index 0 format it to "0.00##" then append " %".

While this gives the desired result it does not explain how to escape % within the string format for parameter 0.